# ffmpeg - Lower volume of background music for dialog in a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have a video with some background music in it.

I wish to add a piece of spoken dialogue at a particular location in the video, such that the background music is lowered for the entire duration of the dialogue audio.

I found a similar solution using `sidechaincompress`, which just works for mp3. I made some changes to it so that it includes the video too (`-map 0:v`). However, now the audio is cut short as soon as the dialogue ends.

```
ffmpeg -i video-with-bg-music.mp4 -i dialogue.mp3 -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.003:ratio=20[bg];[bg][mix]amerge[final]" -map 0:v -map [final] final.mp4
```

I am not a pro at using ffmpeg and probably don't know what's going on with the `filter_complex`. Please help me out.

**EDIT:**

Output log for solution suggested by @kesh

```
ffmpeg -i video_bg.mp4 -i dialogues.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=0,apad,asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.003:ratio=20[bg];[bg][mix]amix=duration=shortest[out]" -map 0:v -map [out] video_bg_speech.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video_bg.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:01:50.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 157 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 146 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[mp3 @ 0x5577fa3b6740] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'dialogue.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:17.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
File 'video_bg_speech.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> sidechaincompress:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mp3float) -> adelay (graph 0)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  amix (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[Parsed_sidechaincompress_3 @ 0x5577faed3f00] No channel layout for input 1
Output #0, mp4, to 'video_bg_speech.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame=  480 fps=325 q=-1.0 Lsize=     517kB time=00:00:19.87 bitrate= 213.0kbits/s speed=13.5x    
video:353kB audio:152kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.388190%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] frame I:2     Avg QP:15.99  size:136135
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] frame P:121   Avg QP:16.86  size:   603
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] frame B:357   Avg QP:26.34  size:    43
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] consecutive B-frames:  0.6%  0.4%  0.6% 98.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] mb I  I16..4:  2.3% 65.7% 32.1%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.1%  P16..4:  1.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.5%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.8%  L0:55.5% L1:44.5% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] 8x8 transform intra:62.5% inter:56.6%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 89.6% 89.0% 78.7% inter: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] i16 v,h,dc,p: 37%  5%  8% 50%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 16%  6%  6%  9%  9%  9% 10%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 18%  7%  6% 11%  9%  9%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 22% 20% 15%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] ref P L0: 46.3%  2.9% 19.3% 31.5%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] ref B L0: 45.6% 54.0%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] ref B L1: 97.0%  3.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5577fa446040] kb/s:144.26
[aac @ 0x5577fa3b9940] Qavg: 307.060
```

Comment: I think you meant to use [`amix`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) instead of [`amerge`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge-1). The latter uses input streams as independent channels while the former adds sound together. Moreover, `amix` does the normalization on its own so you may not need `sidechaincompress`.

Comment: @kesh, I tried the same command with `amix` but it did not change anything. Do you have a working example?

Comment: See the answer. `sidechaincompress` also stops when the shorter stream ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (the short clip inserted at 3-second mark):

```
[1:a]aresample=44100,adelay=3000,apad,asplit=2[sc][mix];\
[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.003:ratio=20[bg];\
[bg][mix]amix=duration=shortest[out]
```

- `aresample` to match the dialog's sampling rate to the video's.
- `adelay` places the clip at the right position (note the delay is in millisec)
- `apad` extends the short stream indefinitely with silence
- `amix` combines 2 streams and stops when the video audio ends

**Addendum:**

If mp4 has no audio, try:

```
ffmpeg -i video-with-bg-music.mp4 -i dialogue.mp3 \
  -af [1:a]adelay=3000,apad \
  -shortest final.mp4
```

`apad` in the audio filtergraph extends the audio stream, and `-shortest` output option cuts it off when the video stream ends.

**Debug Sample**

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex \
    [1:a]aresample=44100,apad,asplit=2[sc][mix];\
    [0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.003:ratio=20[bg];\
    [bg][mix]amix=duration=shortest[out] \
  -f lavfi -i anoisesrc=d=60:c=pink:r=44100:a=0.5 \
  -f lavfi -i sine=220:4:d=5 \
  -map [out] output.mp3
```

Comment: This worked really well. However, I found that for a video with no sound at all, this runs into an error `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description ... matches no streams.` I think I can add silence using another command, but is it possible to handle the scenario in the `filter_complex` itself?

Comment: Updated the answer. I used `-af` option because there is only one audio stream, but if you need to add multiple dialogues together, change it back to `-filter_complex` with `amix` filter and add `-map`'s.

Comment: I think I jumped the gun. I tried the first one with a few more files. It always ends the background music as soon as the dialogue audio ends.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure you are running the right version? I've added the test case I used to validate my filtergraph, and it is working as advertised.

Comment: I tried your debug sample and it works great for mp3. But, if I try the same with an mp4 and mp3, it causes the problem I have stated above. Here's the command I am using. Is the mapping incorrect? `ffmpeg -i video_with_bg.mp4 -i dialogue.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=0,apad,asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.003:ratio=20[bg];[bg][mix]amix=duration=shortest[out]" -map 0:v -map [out] video_with_bg_dialogue.mp4`

Comment: Nothing looks wrong. A couple things. (1) can you add input stream logs on your OP? (2) if dialog starts at the top, drop `adelay`. Don't think it would make a difference but just in case.

Comment: I have added the output log, for the last file I processed, to the original post. Thanks. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I was going through the documentation of `amerge`. The last line says: *If inputs do not have the same duration, the output will stop with the shortest.* (source: http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/amerge-1.htm.gz). Is that the problem?

Comment: `amerge` yeah, that was the original problem. You aren't using it in your latest command 4 comments above (only `amix`).

Comment: The posted log indicates that the output sampling rate has set to 24k (the lower of the two). What happens if you match the rates (to 44.1k)? (edited my post)

Comment: Tried it just now. The output is still cut short. Do you want to see the log?

Comment: No, but try outputting an mp3 file instead (drop video stream mapping) to see if it's the AAC encoder's doing. If not, check decoder by pre-ripping audio from video_with_bg.mp4. You need to find where the culprit is.

Comment: You are right. If I output to mp3 by dropping the video stream mapping, the entire audio comes out perfect.

Comment: How about if you output audio only to .m4a (should use the same encoder as mp4)?

Comment: Still works great. The entire audio comes out perfect again.